# How to access "+RTS -s" or other memory information from within a Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When running a Haskell program, +RTS -s reports information such as "bytes maximum residency". Is there a way to access this information from within a Haskell program? Is there a library on Hackage that provides this functionality?

If not, is there a way to access the amount of memory currently in use? For example, the amount displayed by the terminal command "top"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `getGCStats` function in the [GHC.Stats](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Stats.html) package.

The `currentBytesUsed` field will report the number of live bytes at the end of the last major GC.

Also note the comments in the docs about having to enable to the RTS `-T` option and perhaps calling `performGC` beforehand.